# Margaliyos family tree

Tags: history, names, rabbis

Many famous rabbanim have had the last name מרגליות. A couple that come to mind are ר' ראובן מרגליות and ר' אפרים מרגליות. Are they related? Where could I find genealogical information on such people?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they are all related, but you can browse some Margolios trees on geni.com.  You will have to give them your email address to become a member, but their not too bothersome and you may be interested in doing your own tree!

Comment: I think this should be a comment.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, it answers WAF's 2nd question "Where can I find genealogical information..."

Comment: Fair (15 charac)